# I would like this program to display a box of asteriks when the user enters the lenght and width of its dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This is my code so far, it works for the most part, however, it displays only zeros. I haven't been able to figure out how to make it display asterisks instead because that's the only way I know how to make it display a 2 dimensional array with something inside.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //ask user input of array numbers
    while (length <= 20 || width <= 20) {
        System.out.print("Enter the length: ");
        length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Width: ");
        width = input.nextInt();
        int[][] myarray = new int[width][length]; //To print all elements in this array  of ints,
        //loops is used to make it shorter and efficient
        for (int w = 0; w < length; w++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < width; l++) {
                System.out.print(" " + myarray[l][w]);//prints it in grid fashion
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any arrays. Unless this is part of a program which would use the arrays for something else later, you can just print asterisks a certain number of times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (length <= 20 || width <= 20) {
        System.out.print("Enter the length: ");
        length = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the Width: ");
        width = input.nextInt();

        for (int w = 0; w < length; w++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < width; l++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks this works but I still don't understand how to do it with an array if I needed to, however, this will do.

Comment: You must fill in the array first and your array must be an array of char.

Answer (score 1):

At this line you are printing out the contents of the int[][] array, which is a 0.

```
System.out.print(" " + myarray[l][w]);//prints it in grid fashion
```

You can change that part to an asterisk to get it to print asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `2D` array to actually hold asterisk characters, you will have to change the type of your array to hold `char` values and do:

```
char[][] myarray = new char[width][length]; 
for (int i=0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   Arrays.fill(myarray[i], '*');
}
```

Comment: Arrays.fill(myarray[i], '*');?? How does this work, it doesn't work with my code

Comment: You need to import [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

change your int array to string array

```
String[][] myarray = new String[width][length]; 

for (int w = 0; w < length; w++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < width; l++) {
        myarray[l][w]="*";
        System.out.print(" " + myarray[l][w]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: can you explain further?